# Cosmos DB. I want all my data in same collection. Can I achieve this with an unlimited collection?

Tags: c#, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

At the momment I'm using Cosmos DB fixed 10 gb where I save all my data in same collection. I want to continue this way. So do I just need to create an unlimited collection. When I do that it ask for a partion key which I don't quite understand what it is for. I have tried to read about it but didn't get much clever. Hope you guys can help me.

Today I create documents like this. Should it be done in another way if using unlimited collection. Thinking about should i declare the partion key somewhere?:

```
protected async Task<bool> CreateDocumentAsync(Resource document)
{
        var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_db.Options.Value.DatabaseName, _db.Options.Value.CollectionName);

        ResourceResponse<Document> result = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxRetryCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                result = await _db.Client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_db.Options.Value.DatabaseName, _db.Options.Value.CollectionName), document);
                break;
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException dex) when (dex.StatusCode.HasValue && (int)dex.StatusCode.Value == 429)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning($"");
                await Task.Delay(dex.RetryAfter);
            }
        }

        if (result == null)
            return false;

        int statusCode = (int)result.StatusCode;
        return statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The partition key value can be specified by providing the `RequestOptions` object with the `PartitionKey` value set.

Your create document line would become:

```
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions{
    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("yourPartitionKeyValueHere");
}

result = await _db.Client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_db.Options.Value.DatabaseName, _db.Options.Value.CollectionName), document, requestOptions);
```

However it does should like you don't understand CosmosDB partitioning which means you can get in really deep pitfall.

The partition key definition should be a property that most of the times if not always, is known to you when you are doing querying or reading of documents.

I highly recommend you watch this video. It will greatly help you understand partitioning: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-documentdb-elastic-scale-partitioning/

On a side note, I can see several mistakes in the way you are using the CosmosDB SDK which I cannot fix in a single answer. For example, the CosmosDB SDK has already logic to handle the retry policy logic on the document client level via the `RetryOptions` object so you don't need to write any custom code. I would suggest you read more of the CosmosDB documentation.